# What are good compression-oriented application programming interfaces (APIs)?

Tags: api, compression

What are good compression-oriented application programming interfaces (APIs)?

Do people still use the
1991 "data compression interface" draft standard, and the
1991 "Stream transformation algorithm interface" draft standard.
(Both [draft standards by Ross Williams](http://www.ross.net/compression/interface.html))?
Are there any alternatives to those draft standards?

(I'm particularly looking for C APIs, but links to compression-oriented APIs in C++ and other languages would also be appreciated).

I'm experimenting with some data compression algorithms.
Typically the compressed file I'm producing is composed of a series of blocks,
with a block header indicating which compression algorithm needs to be used to decompress the remaining data in that block -- Huffman, LZW, LZP, "stored uncompressed", etc.

The block header also indicates which filter(s) need to be used to convert the intermediate stream or buffer of data from the decompressor into a lossless copy of the original plaintext -- Burrows–Wheeler transform, delta encoding, XML end-tag restoration, "copy unchanged", etc.

Rather than use a huge switch statement that selects based on the "compression type", which calls the selected decompression algorithm or filter algorithm, each procedure with its own special number and order of parameters,
it simplifies my code if every algorithm has exactly the same API -- the same number and order of parameters, etc.

Rather than waiting for the decompressor to run through the entire input stream before handing its output to the first filter,
It would be nice if the API supported decompressed output data coming out the final filter "relatively quickly" (low-latency) after relatively little compressed data has been fed into the initial decompressor.
It would be nice if the API could be used in systems that have only one thread or process.

Currently I'm kludging together my own internal API,
re-using existing compression algorithm implementations by
writing short wrapper functions to convert between my internal API and the special number and order of parameters used by each implementation.

Is there an already-existing API that I could use rather than designing my own from scratch?
Where can I find such an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear such an "API" does not exist.
Especially, requirement such as "starting stage-2 while stage-1 is ongoing and unfinished" is completely implementation dependant; and cannot be added later by an API layer.

Btw, Maciej Adamczyk just tried the same as you.
He made an open source benchmark comparing multiple compression algorithms over a block-compression scenario. The code can be consulted here :
http://encode.ru/threads/1371-Filesystem-benchmark?p=26630&viewfull=1#post26630

He has been obliged to "encapsulate" all these different compressor interfaces in order to cope with the difference.
Now for the good thing : most compressors tend to have relatively similar C interface **when it comes to compressing a block of data**. 
AS an example, they can be as simple as this one :
http://code.google.com/p/lz4/source/browse/trunk/lz4.h
So, in the end, the adaptation layer is not so heavy.

Comment: While I agree that an API layer cannot add partial processing to an algorithm that don't yet support it, I hoped to find an API that -- like the Ross Williams API I linked to -- allowed partial processing for those algorithms that supported it, even if the API is forced to use block processing for those algorithms that don't.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting links. I'm a little disappointed that there's not already a standard API. Ah well, I guess I'll continue to kludge together my own internal API.